# What's the problem with PostgreSQL temporary files?

Tags: postgresql

I'm studying PostgreSQL architecture and in almost every book or blog post I read people say that we have to track any increasing of `temp_files` numbers and find the best `work_mem` size to avoid new `temp_file` creation.

But none explain why these `temp_files` are so bad. Could anyone clarify to me why we need to keep the number of `temp_files` low?

Answer (score 1):

Memory is faster than disk.

Anything that can be done only using memory will work faster instead of using the hard disks to store temporary content.

PostgreSQL documentation says:

> work_mem (integer)
>
> Specifies the amount of memory to be used by internal sort operations and hash tables before writing to temporary disk files.

So if you find the proper value of it (which depends on total amount of RAM, number of workers, SQL queries done, etc.) then everything should be able to run from RAM only, hence fast.

If this value is exceeded for some operation, temporary files will be created on disk, and hence the operation will be slower.

So tracking amount of temporary files and investigate if it grows is a possible strategy to get better performances (maybe `work_mem` is just too low, its default value being `4MB`; or it is good but it maxes out currently available RAM and then you need a box with more RAM).

Hence the following tools:

1) `temp_files` in `pg_stat_database` whose value is "Number of temporary files created by queries in this database. All temporary files are counted, regardless of why the temporary file was created (e.g., sorting or hashing), and regardless of the log_temp_files setting."

and

2) `log_temp_files` configurable item whose documentation is:

> Controls logging of temporary file names and sizes. Temporary files can be created for sorts, hashes, and temporary query results. A log entry is made for each temporary file when it is deleted. A value of zero logs all temporary file information, while positive values log only files whose size is greater than or equal to the specified number of kilobytes. The default setting is -1, which disables such logging. Only superusers can change this setting.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently we don't read the same blogs.  It is hard to comment meaningfully on your interpretation of unquoted advice given by unnamed people.

Temp files are great.  Gratuitous use of them is bad.  Things are done faster in memory, provided they actually do fit in memory.  Looking at the number of temp files generated tells you nothing about whether that data they stored "should" have fit into memory, unless you are already intimately familiar with your data and your queries.

Comment: Yes, I'm not intimately familiar with PostgreSQL at all, as I'm studying it right now. But the whole point for me is to understand why these files are created in the first place and how PostgreSQL for default use these files and dispose of them after. And to quote anything, if you type "temporary files" in the PostgreSQL docs, no entry answers the two questions I've pointed above.